# Build React component package with TypeScript to ES5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a shared package for our React applications, it would be much better than duplicate the common modules in each repo. I'd like to use TypeScript for that, because most of our React project is written in TS. The package build is working fine, but I always get this error when I use the shared component in a project:

`Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).`

I tried to compile TS to ES5 with webpack, I also tried to compile TS to ES6 and after recompile it to ES5 with Babel. Both builds are working, but i cannot use the components. I created a package in ES6 and it works as it should, but if its possible I want to write this repo in TS.

webpack.config.js:

```
entry: {
    'package_name': './src/index.ts'
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'package_name.js',
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useBabel": true
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets" : ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

I tried a lot of configuration variants but I get that error every time. Can anybody help, what am I missing here? I think I am really close, but a little piece is just not its place. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

src/components/TestComponent.component.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class TestComponent extends React.Component <any,any> {
    render() {
        return <div>I am a TestComponent</div>;
    }
}
```

src/index.ts:

```
export { TestComponent } from './components/TestComponent.component';
```

Comment: you have some problems with your imports/exports, it's hard to say why this is hapenning without code of your shared lib

Comment: thaks for your answer, I just updated the question with the related code

Comment: hmm when you have `useBabel` set to true you shouldn't specify `module` as  "commonjs". Either remove it or change to "es6".

Comment: if i do that then i am getting this error compile time:
`TS2307: Cannot find module 'react'` but it is there.

Comment: well ... i updated my TS version, now its compiled, but i get the original error.

Comment: I think that you shouldn't use webpack to build library output that would be consumed by other projects, you can use it to run and test your library during development. To produce consumable output you should just compile all files with typescript compiler and that's all. Then in one of your other projects import your compiled main index.js file.
Take a look at these libraries https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design or https://github.com/palantir/blueprint. They are build with react, maybe you will find something helpful.